Backfeed 120v to house from 240v garage B-box
 ^Garage Breaker Box^
Main Breaker in house OFF.
A/C Breaker OFF (the only 240v appliance ).
240v breaker to garage OFF.
Backfeed 120v thru one leg of my 240v breaker box in garage. There is an empty 30a 2 screw breaker. It is an older box and has a brass plate where the common and grounds are attached. Connecting generator power to only one screw ( the red wire side of the box ).
#1) will power cross thu the breaker to black sude of the box?
#2) can power be pulled from the red wire side of my house breaker box witout worry of MWBCs?
Plan
In House
Main OFF (remain off)
A/C OFF (remain off)
Garage Off
Appliances to be powered OFF
In Garage
30A OFF
Connect Non Running generator to special outlet (power to red )
Start generator
Turn 30a breaker ON
Back in house
Turn garage breaker ON
Power appliances as needed (fridge, freezer & Furnace)

The problem is people forget to turn off the main breaker and kill the power workers.  There are simple ways of making this idiot proof(close to idiot proof as possible).  You feed the generator to the main panel with an isolating switch that turns off the main same time as opening the gen feed breaker.

If your objective is to physically locate a generator near (hopefully not in) the garage and to exploit the existing feed wire from the house to the garage as a way to get generator power back to the house, you may not do this.
The very first sentence of your question is the key: "Main breaker in house is off".   That is just not good enough.  It has to be "Main breaker in house is impossible to turn on while generator is running".   And the only way to do that is to install an interlock or transfer switch on the main house panel.
If you want to power the house with your generator you need to install the generator interface (inlet, switch/interlock) on the main panel.
If your generator is 120V, you can move breakers around in your main (and garage) panel so that all the most important 120V loads (fridge, bathroom lights, internet, not necessarily in that order) are on the same phase.

Oops. You're right, interlock can't (practically speaking) be in the subpanel.

NO! You can't do this!
It's not safe or legal to use a suicide cord.  It's not safe or legal to backfeed a panel without a generator interlock.  And it's definitely not safe or legal to backfeed a main panel from a subpanel!
I get the desire to make use of the feeder that already runs from main panel to subpanel, but This Cannot Be Done. We've looked and looked.  At least not at any sane cost - you can always install a MID/isolation switch and have it electrically operate a contactor in the garage, but you're talking stupid money and a battery system to keep the MID alive when the power is out.  And you're still burying data wires, so you might as well just bury power wires, and lay that parallel generator circuit you were trying to avoid.
That's the only sane-cost way to do that. Sorry.  Lay a second circuit from where you want the generator to the main panel.  If I had better advice I would give it.

A 30A-capable generator that only produces 120V is (a) relatively unusual (in fact, more likely can't actually generate close to 30A) (except I just found there are quite a few designed with "RV outlet") and (b) extremely limited as it can't power any 240V loads and can only power half of your 120V loads unless you bridge it to both hots (and then you run into potential MWBC neutral issues). I highly recommend looking into generators that can produce more power with a 240V 30A output.
There are two absolutely key issues here and one secondary issue:
Inlet vs. Outlet
An ordinary receptacle has holes or slots in it for prongs from a plug. That is an outlet. It is use for sending power out of the receptacle. When you are sending power in to a receptacle then it must be the opposite, an inlet with prongs on it, which is used with a plug that has matching holes or slots in it. Here is a 30A example, Leviton brand, from Amazon:

Note that you can use an ordinary extension cord (as long as it is sized appropriately for the particular circuit type) because the male end will go into the outlet on the generator and the female end will go into the inlet on your house.
For safety (especially carbon monoxide concerns) the inlet should be mounted on the outside of your house or garage, not inside, as that will help make sure you actually run the generator outside.
Generator Interlock
An interlock is a device, typically a couple pieces of specially designed metal that only allow one of a pair of breakers to be on at a time. This is required (unless you have an automatic transfer switch which would include an equivalent automatic mechanism) to use a generator in place of utility power because otherwise someone will go through the sequence of steps incorrectly (stuff happens, particularly when there are storms going on and/or people are worried about getting the power on to keep refrigerators and/or HVAC running) and potentially zap a utility worker.
Correction: If your generator inlet is connected through a subpanel then the subpanel feed must have an interlock in the main panel. Which effectively means the only loads that could be on the subpanel would be loads powered only when on generator power. Which basically makes the subpanel useless in most circumstances. Which means running a fresh 10 AWG cable (in which case I recommend /3 for future expansion to 240V even though /2 will do for 120V) or 10 AWG wires in conduit from the main panel to wherever the inlet is installed (i.e., even if the inlet will be near an existing subpanel).
Ground/Neutral
Based on the description, it sounds like you have a single bar for neutral ("common") and ground in the subpanel. That is not allowed any more. This is an important issue in general, independent of the generator installation.
If the subpanel is very old and there is no separate ground wire (or metal conduit as ground) between the main panel and subpanel and that was legitimate at the time the subpanel was installed then that is OK. Otherwise, you need to separate ground and neutral in the subpanel by installing a separate ground bar (if there isn't one already installed), removing the neutral/ground bond (if there is one) and moving wires as needed so that neutral wires are only on the neutral bar and ground wires are only on the ground bar.

My generator has a 3 prong 30a 120v outlet. I have a cord to go from it to a 3 prong receptical simalar to the one you shared(i called it a special outlet). I plan on only using one leg at 120v in the house.

That's probably a "30A RV outlet". One option is to do everything except the inlet for 240V - i.e., use a double 30A breaker (that costs very little), and run /3 cable instead of /2 and then just cap one of the hots in the inlet box. Then if in the future you want to get a larger generator you will be all set - just replace the inlet. Interlocks are always for double-breakers anyway (but will work with a single breaker).

Added photo of garage box showing the ground/common plate

That must be pretty old - except for my 1950s fuse boxes (replaced 2 years ago), I have never seen ground/neutral like that - normally each is a straight strip of screws with the wires going under the screw ends rather than needing to hook around the heads. Can you upload a picture of the label on the left side?

Pic added, not home to take a clear version.  Was only interested which side of the box Breakers recieved power from.

Fascinating. That panel is from Square D, which is a good brand. But "XO" appears to be a totally obsolete type of panel/breaker. But that is clearly a neutral bar, which can be disconnected from ground and presumably a ground bar added...somewhere.

Can I use as is?

It is likely grandfathered. But the bigger problem, as jay613 spotted first, but which I agree (and added to my answer): you must have an interlock and that must be in the main panel, so the only practical way to do this is to run a 30A feed from your main panel to a generator inlet. Which ends up meaning the subpanel isn't relevant at all. With one small possible exception: If you have conduit between main panel and subpanel and sufficient space in the conduit (there are online calculators to determine that) then

you may find it easier to run individual wires through the conduit to the subpanel and then out (via conduit or transition to cable) to the inlet rather than a direct run from the main panel to the inlet - i.e., using the subpanel as a point to pass through (a glorified junction box).
